# WindowsUI Composition OriginateException in CreateEffectFactory

Tags: windows, uwp, win2d

I'm getting a lot of exceptions thrown in my app from the Win2d libraries, I'm trying to apply a blur to a background of an element on the load event.

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this);
        this.backgroundContainer.Size = new Vector2((float)this.backgroundGrid.ActualWidth, (float)this.backgroundGrid.ActualHeight);

        // Create background color
        this.backgroundColorSprite = visual.Compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        this.backgroundColorSprite.Size = this.backgroundContainer.Size;
        var darkColor = App.DynamicThemeing.BaseThirtyColor.GetValueOrDefault(Colors.Transparent);
        darkColor.A = 215;
        this.backgroundColorSprite.Brush = visual.Compositor.CreateColorBrush(darkColor);
        this.backgroundContainer.Children.InsertAtBottom(this.backgroundColorSprite);

        // Create the blur effect to be used.
        var blurEffect = new GaussianBlurEffect
        {
            Name = "Blur", 
            BlurAmount = 10.0f, 
            BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard, 
            Optimization = EffectOptimization.Balanced, 
            Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("source")
        };
        var effectFactory = visual.Compositor.CreateEffectFactory(blurEffect, new[] { "Blur.BlurAmount" });
        var effectBrush = effectFactory.CreateBrush();
        effectBrush.SetSourceParameter("source", visual.Compositor.CreateBackdropBrush());
        this.backgroundBlurSprite = visual.Compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        this.backgroundBlurSprite.Brush = effectBrush;
        this.backgroundBlurSprite.Size = this.backgroundContainer.Size;
        this.backgroundContainer.Children.InsertAtBottom(this.backgroundBlurSprite);
    }
```

Stack trace:
https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ag5-nrX1qf58s6ZrQtwxHXl50oMulQ

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] since we cannot reproduce your issue with code snippet above?

Comment: I'm also unable to reproduce the issue however, it is being reported via analytics as 100s of crashes per day. I'm not sure how to further debug the issue

Comment: - Check ActualWidth and ActualHeight they might be NaN


- Replace App.DynamicThemeing.BaseThirtyColor.GetValueOrDefault(Colors.Transparent);
        darkColor.A = 215; with Color.FromArgb(215,0,0,0)